# Mobile Web App: what is the maximum size of the cache that could be stored in the device memory for the offline usage of the web app?

Tags: android, ios, html, html5-appcache, iphone-web-app

I have to develop a web app that could be used both online and offline on iOS7, iOS8 and Android. The app has a lot of contents and images, because it is a brochure app with more than 300 products, each one with image gallery. That's why I'm scared that the device is not able to fully cache the whole application.
Online I can only find infos related to iOS5 (cache size = 5MB) but nothing more updated than this:now we have iOS8 so maybe the cache size limits have been increased...

Answer (score 0):

Maximum appcache size for android devices is limited to 5 MB. But i could not found issue in apple products such as iPhone, iPad, iPod..